# Как переместить контрольные точки(вершины фигур) курсором мыши и переписать их новые положения в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5, pyqt

Знаю, что для этого действия нужно использовать функции а ля: **mousePressEvent, mouseMoveEvent, mouseReleaseEvent**, но пока что не понимаю как.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen, QColor, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QPoint

areas = [
    [(540, 420), (620, 300), (370, 140), (250, 390)],
    [(60, 30), (550, 310), (50, 520)],
    [(200, 500), (370, 390), (170, 200)]
]

EDIT_AREA = True
EDIT_TRAJECTORY = True


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widthApp, self.heightApp = 700, 550
        self.pos = QPoint()
        self.pos_list = []
        self.scale = 10
        self.color = QColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.brush = QBrush(self.color)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, self.width(), self.height())
        self.setWindowTitle('Trajectory')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.drawLine(self.qp)

    def drawLine(self, qp):
        path = QPainterPath()
        x_min, y_min = None, None
        x_max, y_max = None, None

        for trajectory in areas:

            for x, y in trajectory:
                if (x_min is not None) and (y_min is not None):
                    x_min = min(x, x_min)
                    y_min = min(y, y_min)
                else:
                    x_min, y_min = x, y

            for x, y in trajectory:
                if (x_max is not None) and (y_max is not None):
                    x_max = max(x, x_max)
                    y_max = max(y, y_max)
                else:
                    x_max, y_max = x, y

            delta_x = x_max - x_min
            delta_y = y_max - y_min

            scale_x = (self.width() - 40) / delta_x
            scale_y = (self.height() - 40) / delta_y
            scale = min(scale_x, scale_y)

        def map_point(x, y):
            x = (x - x_min) * scale
            y = (y - y_min) * scale

            # Центровка x, y
            x = x + (self.width() - delta_x * scale) / 2
            y = y + (self.height() - delta_y * scale) / 2
            y = self.height() - y
            return x, y

        def draw_area(area):
            path = QPainterPath()
            qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.red))
            x, y = map_point(area[0][0], area[0][1])
            path.moveTo(x, y)
            for x, y in area[1:]:
                x, y = map_point(x, y)
                path.lineTo(x, y)
            x, y = map_point(area[0][0], area[0][1])
            path.lineTo(x, y)
            qp.drawPath(path)

            if EDIT_AREA:
                path = QPainterPath()
                qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.black))
                for x, y in area:
                    x, y = map_point(x, y)
                    self.qp.drawEllipse(x-3, y-3, 6, 6)
                qp.drawPath(path)

        for area in areas:
            draw_area(area)

        qp.drawPath(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы неудачно сократили пример, он не запускается.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Поправил. @S.Nick

Answer (score 1):

Переопределяете методы работы с мышью. В press проверяете, что мышь захватила точку и если да, то сохраняете ее координаты. В move проверяете, если координаты сохраненной точки валидны (не None), тогда меняете их на новые, получаемые от аргумента move. В release опять устанавливаете координаты текущей точки в None.

```
class MainWindow (...):
    def mousePressEvent: # <- подсказка: тут есть аргумент с координатами курсора мышки, см. доку
        # Проверяем что захватили какую-либо точку 
        # Если да, то сохраняем ее, допустим индекс

        self.pointIndex = ...

        self.update() # Обновляем сцену и рисуем выделенную точку как-нибудь

    def mouseMoveEvent: # <- подсказка: тут есть аргумент с координатами курсора мышки. 
        if self.pointIndex not None:
            #Да! Мы захватили точку двигаем ее
            point[self.pointIndex] = ... #Новые координаты
            update() # обновляем положение точки на экране

    def mouseReleaseEvent: # <- подсказка: тут есть аргумент с координатами курсора мышки.
        self.pointIndex = None # Все, с точкой поработали, сдвинули. Свобода!
        update() # перерисовка снятия захвата точки
```

Это общая схема работы, наводящая на мысль.